# What does the notation $C^0([-1,1])$ in the following example mean?

Tags: calculus, notation

The following function series is given.

For $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $C^0([-1,1])$
\begin{equation}
   f_n(x) =
   \begin{cases}
     0 &  -1 \le x \le -\frac{1}{n} \\
     1 +nx &  -\frac{1}{n} < x \le 0 \\
     1 & 0 < x \le 1 
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
What does the symbol $C^0([-1,1])$ mean?
Sorry if this question is very basic, but googling didn't help.

Comment: it means continuous, including one-sided continuous at the endpoints.

Comment: it would appear that you are being introduced to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Comment: $C^0(X)$ is the space of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$ (or something similar in place of $\mathbb{R}$) on the space $X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any set $X$, $C^0(X)$ is simply the set of all real-valued (or complex-valued) continuous functions on the set $X$.  It is also often denoted $C(X)$.

Generally, $C^k(X)$ denotes the set of functions on $X$ for which **at least** the first $k$ (partial) derivatives exist and are continuous.  So with $k=0$, there are no differentiability requirements, and $C^0$ contains all the continuous functions, differentiable or not.